# Normalization vs DeNormalization when using a JSON client with a JAVA/RDBMS stack

Tags: java, javascript, json, angularjs, normalization

I have a Angular JS JSON client interfacing with a JAVA/MySQL stack.
As MySQL is an RDBMS, all my data is normalized (first three forms of course).

My question can be illustrated with the following example.

I have an Example object and a User object returned by the server.

```
Example - [{
userId:1,
...
...
..
},
{
userId:2,
...},
{
userId:3,
...}];

User - [
{
userId - 1,
firstName - "John",
lastName - "Doe",
..
},
{
userId - 2,
firstName - "Jane",
lastName - "Doe",
..
}, {...}...
]
```

When I look through the Example collection using Angular "example_entry in example" and display the Example collection elements, I only have the userId readily available. But if I want to display the firstName and lastName, I can't do it as it's in a different "User" collection.
I have to write a helper Angular controller/service method to get the firstName, lastName from User collection and tie it with Example collection objects.

To avoid this problem, I could De-Normalize the Java Ojbects and send out ready to use JSON like this..

```
Example - [{
userId:1,
firstName - "John",
lastName - "Doe",
...
...
..
},
{
userId - 2,
firstName - "Jane",
lastName - "Doe",
...},
{
userId:3,
...}];
```

But is this good/bad/terrible? Because now my Java Domain Objects have firstName, LastName duplicated in the Example Object and also the User Object. Any advise on which route is better?

```
De-Normalize and have ready to use JSON
Keep Data Normalized to avoid duplication and write converter methods on the Client as needed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my take on this. When it comes to displaying\listing data I am not worried about the Domain model\classes. For me the data returned should match as much as possible the UI display requirements. Here the intent is to show data to user and not much decision making is done of such screens.

But if data needs to be changed\updated one needs to be more careful of what is send, which entities take part in the updation. Keeping data consistent becomes priority and de-normalization may not be right fit in such cases.

Comment: Does it mean I should leave the Backend Java Classes as-is and write helper methods to convert the server-side JSON to a de-normalized JSON? Thanks.

Comment: If it is listing of data, create a view with the required fields in DB and just query it through your app code, no transformation required. For a entity update\ data update scenarios send the correct data entity instead of doing any denormalization on bakend

Comment: But wouldn't that make db storage inefficient with Denormalization? Now if the fName or lName changes, it needs to be updated in more than one place. Also the storage space used now is more. Are these non-issues?

Comment: I am not talking about storage at all. Storage should be normalized. But you can always do joins in DB and return data in denormalized form instead of returning multiple tables or making multiple requests.

Answer (score 5):

You should denormalize your data when you send it to your UI layer.

If your data is in a database, that is a great place for normalized data. 
Use a view that abstracts that normalization and query against the view. The view lets you join tables together to get denormalized data from your database.

In the UI layer you want to have clear, simple display - that's when angular shines best. Unless you are displaying very large amounts of data on the screen or sending huge amounts over the net, you'll fare much better by just sending a denormalized record straight from your db. The DB is great at doing joins and other data querying functions - it is built for that. Javascript *can* do that, but it isn't the best use of it.